How to concatenate two arrays in nunjucks
I have two arrays, arr1 and arr2. I want to concatenate (append all items if arr2 in arr1) both arrays and store in arr3. How to achieve this with nunjucks?

you can use javascript concat method in the template like:
{% set arr1 = [1, 2, 3] %}
{% set arr2 = ["first", "second", "third"] %}
{% set arr3 = arr1.concat(arr2) %} 

